# How to assign a Float in an Array to a Binding<String> in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui

I have a Binding like this:

```
@State var entires: [Entry]
```

Where `Entry` has one property called `amount` which is a `float`.

Now I'm trying to add it to a `TextField` inside a List:

```
List {
    ForEach(entries, id: \.self) { (entry: Entry) in
        TextField("Amount", text: "\(entry.amount)")
    }
}
```

Then its telling me that its a `String` and not `Binding<String>`. But where to place the `$` to have it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible solution (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
struct Entry {
    var amount: Float
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var entries: [Entry] = [Entry(amount: 1.0)]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(entries.indices, id: \.self) {
                self.row(for: $0)
            }
        }
    }

    func row(for index: Int) -> some View {
        let text = Binding<String>(
            get: { String(self.entries[index].amount) },
            set: { self.entries[index].amount = Float($0) ?? 0 }
        )
        return TextField("Amount", text: text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a create a `Binding` yourself that does the `Float`-`String` conversion. You can achieve this using the `Binding(get:set:)` initialiser.

You also need to call `ForEach` on `entries.indices` and access each `Entry` by index, since the loop variable is immutable, so you couldn't pass `entry` directly to a mutable `Binding` if you iterated over `entries` instead of `entries.indices`.

```
ForEach(entries.indices, id: \.self) { index -> TextField<Text> in
    let binding = Binding<String>(
        get: { self.entries[index].amount.description },
        set: { if let newValue = Float($0) { self.entries[index].amount = newValue }}
    )
    return TextField("Amount", text: binding)
}
```